# Rails - Component from Component Library and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

I have a rails app I'm working on. I've hit a bit of a wall with the database structure. I have `Users`. These users have `Projects`, and the projects have components. I want to have the user be able to choose from some existing components then edit the values. I want the components they choose from to come from a database. And I want the resulting component to be a new component. To make life a little more confusing, there are different types of components, I'd like to DRY up these classes into something like

```
Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  # component stuff
end

SubComponent < Component
  # sub-component stuff
end
```

Then in 1 controller and 1 view I'd like the user to be able to handle all the components.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: how would you do this? When I try with STI it messes up paths a lot. I'm kinda looking for insight on what the best approach to this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since this question was kinda vague, I'm going to just post what I've come up with, so if people stumble upon this question there is at least something useful here.

This is a example app I've made to illustrate some aspects of STI and nested resources together.
http://rails-example-association.herokuapp.com

There is a link to the source on github on the site.